# Происходит повторная отправка формы при обновлении страницы

Tags: php, html, css, sql, phpmyadmin

У меня есть небольшая программка, добавляю записи в базу данных.
Но при обновлении страницы запись добавляется заново, как это можно исправить?
[image: Скриншот]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>И-31</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<body>
  <?php require_once("connect.php");?>
  <header class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-body border-bottom shadow-sm">
    <p class="h5 my-0 me-md-auto fw-normal">И-31 program</p>
    <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 me-md-3">
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Главная</a>
    </nav>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Выход</a>
  </header>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Группа" name="Groupe">
    <input type="text" placeholder="ФИО" name="Family">
    <button name="button">Добавить</button>
  </form>
  <?php require_once("inset.php"); ?>
  <?php require_once("select.php");?>
</body>
</html>


    <?php //действия при нажатии на кнопку
    if (isset($_POST["button"])) {
      $a = $_POST["Groupe"];
      $b = $_POST["Family"];
      $query = "INSERT INTO `d_base` (`id`, `groupe`, `FIO`) VALUES (NULL, '$a', '$b');";
      $result = mysqli_query($connecting, $query);
    }
  ?>

    <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM `d_base`"; $query = mysqli_query($connecting, $query);
    echo "<ul>";
      while ($r = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
        echo "<li>$r[1] - $r[2]</li>";
      }
  ?>
```

В интернете был ответ, что поместить скрипты в отдельные файлы нужно и подключить, но не помогло.

Comment: Или вводите одноразовые CSRF, или используйте отправку по AJAX.

Comment: В целом нужно отличать отправку формы от простой загрузке. Например у формы поставить action с GET параметром, а при совершении действий на сервере редиректить на страницу без параметров.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это "bad practice".

Comment: @VladimirGonchar что именно? По мне тут весь код - bad practice. Так что тут из советов уже ничего не bad))

Comment: @VladimirGonchar что именно?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, что в чем-то накосячил, я новичок просто) Изучаю php 2 недели всего

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так у него и отличается, ` if (isset($_POST["button"])) {`.

Comment: @POLTERGEIST вот поэтому и советую вам пройтись полностью по обучающей книге, в которой скажут как правильно и почему или курс. Не знаю как вы сейчас изучаете, но это выглядит некорректно, а, значит, не то изучаете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, какую книгу посоветуете прочитать?

Comment: Котеров, РНР7 в подлиннике. Вот как раз после этой книги не будет возникать вопросов, "почему повторно отправляется"